# AngularJs - Subproperty filtering as AND operation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've been trying to filter an array using Angular like this:

```
{{ (array | filter: { property: { subproperty: 'value' } }).length }}
```

and it works great.

Then I tried:

```
{{ (array | filter: { property: { subproperty1: 'value1', subproperty2: 'value2' } }).length }}
```

and noticed that Angular interprets this as an OR operation for the 2 subproperties.

How do I filter by 2 or more subproperties as an AND operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you trying to do basically adding an `additional filter` to the current one. Try using the following and it should work as an `AND` filter.

```
 {{ (array | filter: { property: { subproperty1: 'value1'}} 
           | filter: { property: { subproperty2: 'value2'}}).length }}
```

-- EDIT --

According to the angularjs docs:

> A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained
>    by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" ***AND*** property phone containing "1".

I prepared the following filter (arguments) based on the pointers in the docs and it works perfect for me.

```
{{ (array | filter: { property.subproperty1 : 'value1',
                      property.subproperty2 : 'value2' }).length }}
```

[functional fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vX2Ph/)

P.S. - I also tried to figure out why your code was acting as an OR operator, but it never worked for me. [non-functional fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WS99u/1/)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I ended up doing; however I was wondering if there is any syntax for specifying an actual AND operation between properties, the reason for that is that I might have to add multiple (5+) subproperties.